# Download images asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I am using the following code to download images. Can someone confirm the images are being downloaded asynchronously as they would appear to be?  Normally, they download rapidly but every now and then the UI freezes for a minute while data comes through so something would appear to be awry:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1

  NSString *picURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://~/pics/%@",picname];
    NSURL *urlPicUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:picURL];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{ 
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picURL]];
         if (imgData) { 
            UIImage *imageCache = [[UIImage alloc] init];
            imageCache = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
            if (imageCache) { 
                [self saveImage:imageCache asPicName:picname];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
                }); 
            } 
        } 
    });
```

**EDIT:**

Here is code to save image.

```
- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image asPicName: (NSString*)picname
{
    if (image != nil)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          [NSString stringWithString: picname] ];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the ' saveImage:' method ?

Comment: Why are you asynchronously calling the main queue? Code should be dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}) ;

Comment: @MarkBourke Why? There's nothing wrong with what the OP is doing in that regard.

Comment: When I log imgData, I see that the freeze occurs during download.

Comment: Apart from your problem it's a waste of time and resources to get the (same) `documents` directory for each single image rather than getting it once in `viewDidLoad` and save it into a variable.

Comment: PS: Consider using `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` which works asynchronously by default.

Comment: simple question but if I create a property in the class from which the VC inherits, could I just save the documents path as a property in that?  I use that path a lot.